# How to automatically open generated JSDoc with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using the plugin gulp-jsdoc3 to generate JSDoc (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsdoc3).

My questions are :

1. How to automatically open the generated documentation after it has been generated by gulp?
2. I am using browserSync for this project, can it be achieved with browserSync?

Here are my gulp tasks to generate the JSDoc :

```
gulp.task('doc', ['doc-clean'], function (cb) {
    gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js'], {read: false})
        .pipe(jsdoc(cb));
});

gulp.task('doc-clean', function (done) {
    clean('./docs', done);
});
```